# Why does StackTrace.GetFrames not return the reference directly?

Tags: c#

Here is the source code of `StackTrace`.

```
public virtual StackFrame GetFrame(int index)
{
    if ((frames != null) && (index < m_iNumOfFrames) && (index >= 0))
        return frames[index+m_iMethodsToSkip];

    return null;
}

public virtual StackFrame [] GetFrames()
{
    if (frames == null || m_iNumOfFrames <= 0)
        return null;

    // We have to return a subset of the array. Unfortunately this
    // means we have to allocate a new array and copy over.
    StackFrame [] array = new StackFrame[m_iNumOfFrames];
    Array.Copy(frames, m_iMethodsToSkip, array, 0, m_iNumOfFrames);
    return array;
}
```

Why doesn't `GetFrames` just return `frames`? If it does not want caller to modify the frames, why does `GetFrame` return the reference instead of copy?

By the way,  [StackFrame](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stackframe.cs) has no method or property to modify itself.

Comment: I think you have answered yourself - StackFrame is immutable class, while array is mutable so returning array reference will allow user to modify referenced object

Comment: Doesn't the comment itself already answer this?

Comment: The array contains stack lines which should be skipped(f.e. [diagnostic-trace](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Transactions/System/Transactions/Trace/DiagnosticTrace.cs,18321b1d35ae3e44)). This [`m_iMethodsToSkip`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/stacktrace.cs,c100290c16f621f2) field is skipped in the `GetFrames `, that's why the complete array cannot be returned but only a subset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't `GetFrames` just return `frames`?

Well, the `frames` variable is the internal storage. So you, as a receiver of the return value could change the internal storage variable by just setting the indexes of the array. To prevent that, it copies the immutable objects to a new array (with a better size than the stack size which the array has).

Also, as the comment states: *We have to return a subset of the array.* So not the entire array is returned. An example can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Transactions/System/Transactions/Trace/DiagnosticTrace.cs,740): all methods from `DiagnosticTrace` are filtered out.

> Why does `GetFrame` return the reference instead of copy?

Because a frame is immutable, you can't change it. There is no need to copy it since it is read-only.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Added your sample. Thanks.